# Handing a response in a controller after segueing to another controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2, cloudinary

I'm using Cloudinary to store images that the user uploads in my Swift 2 app. I have a question about the flow/architecture. Currently what I'm doing is that as soon as the user uploads the image, I send the image to Cloudinary, send the image id to my server, and immediately segue the user to the next screen. With the id, I can later reference the image on Cloudinary, so I technically don't need to wait for the response back from Cloudinary and keep the user waiting. Yes, if there is an upload failure, I won't know, but those are edge cases. This is the code I have:

```
@IBAction func btnRegister(sender: AnyObject) {
    let pictureId = self.btnImage.currentImage == NSUUID().UUIDString
    self.uploadToCloudinary(pictureId)

    //send to my server
    User.register(_userName, password: _password, picture: pictureId)
        .success { (value) in
         self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Home", sender: self)
         }
}

func uploadToCloudinary(pictureId:String){
        let image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(btnImage.currentImage!)! as NSData
        let uploader = CLUploader(_cloudinary, delegate: self)
        uploader.upload(image, options: ["public_id":pictureId], withCompletion:onCloudinaryCompletion, andProgress:onCloudinaryProgress)
}

func onCloudinaryCompletion(successResult:[NSObject : AnyObject]!, errorResult:String!, code:Int, idContext:AnyObject!) {
        //
}
```

However, I now realized that I need to save some additional details such as "version" that Cloudinary sends me back, so I might need to do something on onCloudinaryCompletion to send those details to my server. The thing is--that means I have to now make the user wait till the image finishes uploading before I can segue them to the next screen.

So my questions:

1. In Swift, can I still do stuff in the completion handler even if the user has segeued away to another view controller? That way I can keep my current flow, and just save the successResult whenever it returns, but I don't have to keep my user waiting.
2. Is there another recommended flow for doing something like this? Any suggestions welcome.
3. For those of you who are familiar with Cloudinary--is there a way to know the version before uploading? Because all I really need is the version, and if I can know that before uploading, I can save that along with the picture Id, and forget about the onCloudinaryCompletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Cloudinary perspective you could use one of the following approaches:

- Avoid using versions - URL versions are basically just a mean for busting the cache in case the image is updated. If this isn't essential then you can just remove it from the URL.
  See: https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520912-What-are-image-versions-
- Use our Webhooks support - this will tell Cloudinary to notify your server with all the necessary details (including Public ID and Version) regarding the uploaded file, which you can then store together on your DB.
  See: http://cloudinary.com/blog/webhooks_upload_notifications_and_background_image_processing

Comment: For the first bulletpoint, I think I read somewhere that the version is required for images stored in folders?

Comment: It's the default behaviour of the SDKs to add `v1/` to all URLs containing folders structure. It can be omitted with no change in the results.

The only impact will be in case of invalidations as explained here: http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#invalidating_cached_images_on_the_cdn